# can we just check an obvious solution of a functional equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

In a functional equation, if a solution is obvious, can we just check it and say that this is the solution?

Comment: You can only say: "it is _a_ solution".

Comment: like in equation f(x+y) - f(x-y) = 4xy  the obvious solution is f(x) = x^2

Comment: As @Watson pointed out, it is **a** solution (i.e., one possible solution).  There may be others.

Comment: How can i prove that there are not any other solution?

Comment: @MuhammadSaboor, I have answered your question with respect to proving there are no other solutions.

Comment: Only your instructor(s) can answer this.  It seems you are short cut so you don't need to show your work? (If you know an answer at the get go, then it shouldn't be difficult to explain how you know it.)

Answer (score 3):

In general, that method will work fine for picking out *particular* solutions to functional equations, but it may not get you *every* solution to the equation. Consider the functional equation

$$
f(x)\cdot f(-x) = 1.
$$

One solution is $f(x) = 1$. Another solution is $f(x) = e^x$. In fact, there is an entire family of solutions of the form $f(x) = c^x$ for $c \neq 0$. So, to answer your question, it is OK to specify a particular solution, but you should be careful when claiming you have found *the* solution when infinitely many solutions may exist.

If you want to claim that you have found *the* solution, say $f$, to a functional equation, you will have to show that if there is any other solution $g$, that $g = f$. This says that $f$ is the *unique* solution of the functional equation in consideration. As I have already exemplified, this is not always possible to show.

I am going to give an example of a situation where one can show that the solution $f$ of a functional equation is *the* solution. Incidentally, this is almost coming verbatim from the Wikipedia page for "functional equation." However, the way they illustrate uniqueness is not the most general way, so I am taking the time to demonstrate the general method here.

Consider the functional equation $f(x + y)^2 = f(x)^2 + f(y)^2$.
Putting $x = y = 0$ shows that $f(0) = 0$. Putting $y = -x$ shows that $0 = f(x)^2 + f(-x)^2$. Squares are always nonnegative, so the sum of squares is nonnegative, and hence $f(x)^2=0$ implies that $f(x) = 0$, identically.

*Suppose there was a distinct function $g$ that also satisfied $g(x+y)^2 = g(x)^2 + g(y)^2$*. Since $g$ is distinct from $f$, there exists $x^\ast \in \Bbb R$ such that $g(x^\ast) \neq 0$. Then, by applying the same procedure of putting $y = -x^\ast$, we see that $0 = g(x^\ast)^2 + g(-x^\ast)^2$. However, the square of a positive number is itself positive, and squares are nonnegative, so $g(-x^\ast)^2 \geq 0$. The sum of a number that is greater than zero and a number that is at least zero is greater than zero. We see that no such $g$ can exist, and we conclude that $f = 0$ is the *unique* solution to $f(x+y)^2 = f(x)^2 + f(y)^2$.

Comment: How will i prove this statement:  if there is any other solution g, that g=f

Comment: @MuhammadSaboor, In general, this may be quite difficult, and there may be not be a unique solution. However, the strategy is to *assume* that there is another distinct solution to your equation, and to demonstrate that this distinct solution is not distinct after all, and that it is actually the original solution you found. In general, your best bet is to simply write down *all* the solutions of the functional equation.

Comment: Can you give an example for the above strategy?

Comment: @MuhammadSaboor, done. Also, please see the Wiki page for functional equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation. They also show that $f$ is unique in this example by a method that works because of the example. However, I wanted to show you what the most general strategy would look like applied to an example, hence me going through the trouble of editing my original post. Hope that helps.

Comment: @AOrtiz I think your overall answer is good and I upvoted it. However, the example you gave seems redundant since you had already shown that any function satisfying the functional equation must be identically $0$. I don't think it's a illuminating example for the method you wanted to propose.

Comment: @BigbearZzz, Thanks for that. I chose this example primarily because it was readily available on the Wiki page. I think that the OP just needed to get a sense for how this kind of argument develops. I agree that the proof is redundant, albeit makes the style of the argument explicit. In general, the OP will not have such a nice case as this one, and I think it is good to be explicit about how the argument would look in the general case. Noted that this example is not the best. Do you know of any other examples the OP could use to practice this kind of argument?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not enough. If you have a functional equation, "solving" the functional equation means finding every solution. That is, your solution set $S$ must be such that a function $f$ is a solution to the equation if and only if $f \in S$.

In practice, what this means is "guessing and checking" will practically never work, because you probably don't have every solution.